# How to reverse check if object exisit in many to many django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models:

```
Model Student:
     name = models.CharField()
     ..... ....
     wishlist = models.ManyToManyField(University, blank=True)

Model University:
      name = models.CharField()
      ...... . .. . . . .
```

Basically am just creating a wishlist by which user can like on a university and then add it to their wishlist ! ( am expressing this via a heart icon ), So when user reclicks on same item then it will remove it from the wishlist, thats it !

The problem is that, how to check if a user has liked particular university ?

here is my code:

```
def index(request):
    univesity = University.objects.filter(is_approved=True)
    context = {'univesity': univesity}
    return render(request, 'search/index.html', context)
```

above is where i fetch all university for searching purpose ! In this i need to check if the use have already added the university to the wishlist relationship. And if its true then the heart icon will turn into red else empty color !

And now this is how i show on template

```
{% if data.student_set.all %}
     <button><em class="icon ni ni-heart-fill" ></em></button>
{% else %}
     <button><em class="icon ni ni-heart"></em></button>
{% endif %}
```

It doesnt work the way i expected ! please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if that person liked a university by annotating the `Universities` with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

@login_required
def index(request):
    universities = University.objects.annotate(
        liked=Exists(Student.wishlist.through.objects.filter(
            student=request.user, university_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ))
    ).filter(is_approved=True)
    context = {'universities': universities}
    return render(request, 'search/index.html', context)
```

If `Student` is the user model. If that is not the case, you first should fetch the logged in user, and use that in the `.filter(student=…, …)` part.

Then we can render this in the template with:

```
{% for university in universities %}
    {{ university }}
    {% if university.liked %}
        <button><em class="icon ni ni-heart-fill" ></em></button>
    {% else %}
         <button><em class="icon ni ni-heart"></em></button>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Oh god, i couldnt understand annotate - is that this much hard to reverse lookup ?

Comment: @sixovov947: not to filter, but here we make a subquery to check if there is a student wishlist with as user `request.suer` and with `university_id` the primary key of the `University`.

Comment: whats an "OuterRef" and doing subquery is considered as an extra query and its that efficient ?

Comment: @sixovov947: no subqueries are part of the query, so all the work is done by the database, not by extra queries from Django. `OuterRef` refers to a field that does not belong to the subquery, but to the outer query (so here a query of the `University` model, we thus refer to the primary key of the `University` for which we determine if the post was liked).

Comment: It gives an error "'Exists' object has no attribute 'filter'"

Comment: @sixovov947: sorry, I forgot to close a bracket, that should be fixed now.

Comment: I have added the same code which you have given, and where is the "pk" coming from ?

Comment: Yes, its working now thanks ! But where is the pk populated from ?

Comment: @sixovov947: `pk` refers always to the primary key field. So if you did not set a primary key, than it is equivalent to the `id` field. It is populated by the *outer* query: the database will perform the subquery for *each* university, and the `OuterRef('pk')` thus takes the primary key of that university.

Comment: @sixovov947: if student is not the user model, you will need to first fetch the primary key of the student of the logged in user, and use that in the `student=...` part.

Comment: yes its working amazingly ! But really couldnt understand a thing :( ! Anyways thanks a ton

Comment: @sixovov947: perhaps it can help to take a look at the documentation of the `Exists` subquery.